# Can't figure out why AO is not displaying properly. Very new to blender

Tags: uv-image-editor

Basically I have done an AO map for my character. However, when I render the image shows as below and I cannot figure out why?

Very new to blender so I'm sorry for the noob question.

[image]

Comment: Can you check to see if the normals are inverted? Sometimes when I get a dark result, the normals need reset or inverting.

Comment: Most likely textures not assigned/configured correctly. Tried textured view?

Comment: Are you using cycles? Are you using cycles nodes. What is your material setup like. screenshots?

Comment: Did you assign the image texture to the material?